# HTML/JQuery navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition won't work second time (Firefox only)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, geolocation

I have a strange JQuery issue that I am looking for help with.

I have a page that has the below piece of javascript. When the page loads the first time it works as it should. However if the user moves away but then comes back to the page, the load isn't called, instead it happens about 30 seconds later.

If I have the alert uncommented it all works fine (apart from the popup appearing). This is happening in Firefox only. All other browsers are fine. This is in a MVC3 application. There is no caching on the MVC action either.  Could it be a cache issue somewhere else?

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                $(function () {
                    //alert('1');
                    $('#divNearestTiles').load....
```

Comment: Probably takes 30 secs to get the location, no?

Comment: No I don't think thats it, when the alert is in there it loads instantly after you click through.

Comment: Instead of the alert, try console.log and see how soon it shows up both before and after the user moves away and returns.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have it working now. The load has a sussess function. It turned out to be something in there. A bit odd, bit its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have it working now. The load has a success function. It turned out to be some jquery in there that was upsetting things.